# Notification to the admin when any product goes out of stock in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, out-of-stock

Notification to the admin when any product goes out of stock in Magento 2

I used a module from [GitHub](https://github.com/bharat2762/magento2-admin-low-stock-notification) to send a notification mail to the admin when any product stock quantity below 20,10,5. Also, I need additional customization to send a notification mail for out of stock product to the admin.

Comment: Please mention what you have did so far, and what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: You can create an observer on order place after event. After order place check the product current qty that has been ordered, and if any qty is below 20,10,5 send an email.

Comment: Have you not considered just adding qty below 1 which basically means out of stock

Comment: @Divya can you check this extension :https://github.com/bharat2762/magento2.3.x-admin-low-stock-notification
here you need some minor customization like as per your quantity and this extension also working for magento2.3 and low notification , you received  email

Comment: @RakeshDonga i need it for only magento 2.2.x version

Comment: @divyasekar you have install this extension and useful?

Comment: I was already installed and used it but I have continuously got an undefined function issue in **message.php** that's while I go for https://github.com/bharat2762/magento2-admin-low-stock-notification this 2.2.x module @RakeshDonga

Comment: @Nayem thanks, I was done it by your suggestion.

Comment: @divyasekar Will you accept that as correct answer if i post that comment as answer?

Comment: sure can you post that comment as an answer @Nayem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I created one module it will send daily one email to admin of all out stock product
https://github.com/sunilit42/lowstocknotification

Answer (score 1):

You can create an observer on order place after event. After order place check the product current qty that has been ordered, and if any qty is below 20,10,5 send an email.